# How to standardize data format?

Tags: sql, string, datetime, ms-access, dataformat

I'm having a problem during the data collecting in SQL, apparently, the programmer of one of our production equipments did a update in a MS Access database and changed the date format and it's causing me troubles for lookup specific dates.

Could you recommend how to standardize the dates?

Please have a look on the query results I'm adding here:

```
Prod_Date
-------------
8/24/2020
8/23/2020
8/22/2020
2020-08-24
2020-08-23
2020-08-22
2020-08-21
2020-08-20
2020-08-19
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your edit of removing [tag:sql-server] completely invalidates both answers the OP has at this time.

Comment: @Larnu: but the question clearly states that MS ACCESS is being used, which made the SQL Server tag wrong to begin with

Comment: Access *does* support pass through queries, @a_horse_with_no_name . The OP could easily be using a SQL Server back end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you are not doing DMY, you can simply use `try_convert()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Prod_Date] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('8/24/2020')
,('8/23/2020')
,('8/22/2020')
,('2020-08-24')
,('2020-08-23')
,('2020-08-22')
,('2020-08-21')
,('2020-08-20')
,('2020-08-19')
 
Select *
      ,AsDate = try_convert(date,[Prod_Date])
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Prod_Date   AsDate
8/24/2020   2020-08-24
8/23/2020   2020-08-23
8/22/2020   2020-08-22
2020-08-24  2020-08-24
2020-08-23  2020-08-23
2020-08-22  2020-08-22
2020-08-21  2020-08-21
2020-08-20  2020-08-20
2020-08-19  2020-08-19
```

Answer (score 2):

`date` columns **don't** have a format, which means that your "date" column is not a `date`, but a `varchar`. There's an "easy" way to fix this, fix the data type of the column.

**Hopefully** you only have 2 formats, `yyyy-MM-dd` and `M/d/yyyy`. If so, then we can use this sample set:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Prod_Date varchar(10))

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES ('8/24/2020'),
       ('8/23/2020'),
       ('8/22/2020'),
       ('2020-08-24'),
       ('2020-08-23'),
       ('2020-08-22'),
       ('2020-08-21'),
       ('2020-08-20'),
       ('2020-08-19');
```

First, we need to get the data in an ISO format, specifically I'm going to use `yyyyMMdd`. To do this we need, unfortunately, several nested `CONVERT`s with style codes:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET Prod_Date = TRY_CONVERT(varchar(8),ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(date,Prod_Date,101),TRY_CONVERT(date,Prod_Date,23)),112);
```

Then we can change the data type of the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN Prod_date date; --Add NULL if needed
```

And then you have no formats in your table any more, and the problem no longer can happen.